# Кодировка кириллицы для отправки SMS через GSM модем

Tags: c#, кодировка

Отправляю смс, получаю набор символов. Пытался `sp.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.Default;` - тоже самое. С англ текстом промблем нету.

```
public static string SMSMessage = "привет";
public static string CellNumber = "+77777777";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sp = new SerialPort();
    sp.PortName = "COM12";
    sp.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!sp.IsOpen)
        {
            sp.Open();
            this.sp.WriteLine(@"AT" + (char)(13));
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            this.sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + (char)(13));
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            this.sp.WriteLine(@"AT+CMGS=""" + CellNumber + @"""" + (char)(13));
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            this.sp.WriteLine(SMSMessage + (char)(26));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exception : {0}", ex.Message), "Port Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Так может проблема с принимающей стороны?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов принимающая сторона - моб телефон, я никак не могу на него повлиять.

Comment: Чем пользуетесь для отправки?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов телефон, Нокия 5228. Через СОМ порт.

Comment: Я имел ввиду фреймворк для отправки SMS.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов using System.IO.Ports; using System.Threading; И код который вверху. Вот и все.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");` или `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");`

Comment: а вы не пробовали конвертировать из Encoding.Default в Encoding.UTF8 сам текст перед отправкой?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов тот же результат.

Comment: @Stack        string abc = "привет";
                    var bytes = new List<byte>();
                    foreach (var c in abc)
                     bytes.Add((byte)c);
                    var retValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray());

Теперь приходит смс "?@82B"

Comment: Проблема, очевидно, в `UTF8Encoding.Default == Encoding.Default`. Попробуйте вместо этого `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: @VladD в коде так и стоит ))

Comment: @LittleFox: Это хуже :-\ А что говорит документация, какую кодировку она предписывает?

Comment: @VladD её нет :D. Просто пытаюсь через прогу послать СМС, Англ буквы работают, наши не хотят :(

Comment: насчет документации Вы глубоко ошибаетесь, вот [здесь](http://www.microchip.ua/simcom/SIM900x/AppNotes%20-%20raznoe/SMS%20in%20Pdu%20mode.pdf) очень неплохой мануал, использовал его сам для оформления так сказать библиотеки для отправки смс через gsm модем.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34458/discussion-on-question-by-little-fox-----sms-).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Решил проблему. Кодировка нужна - `UCS2`

```
this.WriteLine("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,25" + (char)(13));
Thread.Sleep(200);
this.sp.WriteLine(StringToUCS2("Привет, привіт !@#%") + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26));
```

---

```
public static string StringToUCS2(string str)
{
    UnicodeEncoding ue = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] ucs2 = ue.GetBytes(str);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < ucs2.Length)
    {
        byte b = ucs2[i + 1];
        ucs2[i + 1] = ucs2[i];
        ucs2[i] = b;
        i += 2;
    }
    return BitConverter.ToString(ucs2).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Все работает на ура! :)

Comment: Не забудьте потом пометить ваш ответ как верный.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать конструктор `new UnicodeEncoding(true, true)` вместо цикла.

Comment: И я бы назвал метод не `StringToUCS2`, а `UCS2ToHex` - иначе не вполне понятно что он делает.

Comment: Точно такой код и подробное описание приводится в статье [Отправляем SMS из .Net приложения на C#](http://habrahabr.ru/post/256687/)

Comment: тут вместо while, внешнего int i и i += 2 можно избавиться. код уменьшится. посмотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Описание отправки сообщений в режиме PDU (Protocol data unit) приводится в статье **[Отправляем SMS из .Net приложения на C#](http://habrahabr.ru/post/256687/)**.

---

**UPDATE**

```
string ToUCS2(string str) {
    byte[] ucs2 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < ucs2.Length; i += 2) {
        var tmp = ucs2[i + 1];
        ucs2[i + 1] = ucs2[i];
        ucs2[i] = tmp;
    }
    return BitConverter.ToString(ucs2).Replace("-", "");
}
```

А в общем случае, как я уже говорил в [комментарии](http://[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483634/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-sms-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-gsm-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC#comment559609_483634]), конвертировать кодировку можно с помощью Encoding.Convert, cм. **[Как прочесть кракозябры "ЇаЁўҐв"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483912/)**

[.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2321/196972)

Comment: и так пытался, не работало. Уже добавил ответ. Оказалось нужна UCS2

Comment: @Bald _"мне кажется разумнее всего было бы удалить данный ответ - так как он не является ответом на вопрос"_ -- в вопросе сказано "Кодировка кириллицы для отправки". в общем случае используется Encoding.Convert. и возможно, что именно этот способ поможет кому-то в дальнейшем.

Comment: @Bald _"ТС уже ответил на свой вопрос,"_ -- вы на время ответа смотрели? а про задержки в сети/серверах не слышали? разница между нашими ответами пара минут. т.е. ответили одновременно. а еще посмотрите комменты под вопросом, там 12 часов назад я написал предложение. и еще вот "[ему стоило запостить свой "достаточный" комментарий как ответ.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2321/196972)". и еще раз спрашиваю: вам делать нечего и вы решили потроллить и поминусировать? :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34463/discussion-between-bald-and-stack).

Comment: На meta.ru.stackoverflow обсуждение: ["Удалять такие ответы или нет?"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2336/)