# Как сместить кнопку и label

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Скрыть" сама эта кнопка и label меняли расположение на форме(также название скрыть меняется на показать). А при нажатии на "Показать" обратно возвращаются на первоначальное расположение. Если задаю новые координаты то при развертывании формы на весь экран свойство Anchor почему то не работает. А если не задаю новые координаты то работает.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonHide.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        zedGraph.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top)));
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    }

    int vkl = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        vkl++;
        if (vkl % 2 == 0)
        {
            buttonHide.Text = "Cкрыть";
            //buttonHide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(877, 510);
            buttonHide.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            tabControl1.Visible = true;
            labelTimeStart.Visible = true;
            textBoxTimeStart.Visible = true;
            labelTimeFinish.Visible = true;
            textBoxTimeFinish.Visible = true;
            //labelBackGround.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 510);
            //zedGraph.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(940, 466);
        }
        else
        {
            buttonHide.Text = "Показать";

            //labelOfAxis1[0].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.labelBackGround.Location.X + 3, this.labelBackGround.Location.Y + 2);
            for (int j = 1; j < countOfAxis; j++)
            {
                //labelOfAxis1[j].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
                //labelOfAxis1[j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(877, 718);
            }
            //buttonHide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(877, 718);
            buttonHide.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            //zedGraph.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(940, 680);
            //zedGraph.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            //| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            //| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            tabControl1.Visible = false;
            labelTimeStart.Visible = false;
            textBoxTimeStart.Visible = false;
            labelTimeFinish.Visible = false;
            textBoxTimeFinish.Visible = false;
            //labelBackGround.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 718);

        }
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделать Dock=DockStyle.None и увеличить Height

Comment: @Stack Подробнее можно

Comment: Мне ширину(высоту) кнопки менять не надо, мне ее расположение надо поменять, может быть можно сделать относительно нижнего правого края формы как то определять координаты, тогда бы свойство   Anchor не понадобилось

Comment: надо большое поле сделать еще больше. т.е. сдвинуть нижнюю границу вниз. вот я и предлагаю это сделать. для подробнее тут нет места. а как ответ писать не буду, а то минусов насобираю как в ответе-предположении [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483634/)