# Как прочесть кракозябры "ЇаЁўҐв"?

Tags: c#, .net, кодировка

Есть строка "ЇаЁўҐв", как ее прочесть? Т.е. ее надо конвертировать из одной кодировки в другую, как это сделать на C#?

---

Дополнение: отвечаю на вопрос для чего это нужно и где такие строки бывают?
Если взять старые флоппи диски, с файлами, созданными в прошлом веке в MS-DOS, то названия файлов бывают примерно такими "ЇаЁўҐв.txt", если смотреть в Windows.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34517/discussion-on-question-by-stack----).

Answer (score 10):

Указать кодировку при чтении содержимого файла. Т.е. для чтения ("перекодирования" при чтении) из 866 достаточно лишь указать Encoding:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\test.txt", "тест!", Encoding.GetEncoding(866));

var text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(866));
```

Если же у вас возник специфический кейс, например, вы получили уже испорченный текст как строку - то достаточно просто сохранить его обратно в байты с указанием неправильной кодировки, и прочитать с указанием правильной:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string bad = "ЇаЁўҐв";
    string good = Convert(bad, 1251, 866);
}

static string Convert(string source, int from, int to)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(from).GetBytes(source);
    return Encoding.GetEncoding(to).GetString(bytes);
}
```

Правда, сработает это только в случае, если чтение байт в неправильной кодировке (по счастливому совпадению!) окажется обратимым. Ниже показан пример, когда это не так.

---

По поводу "перекодировки":

Вы пытаетесь починить последствия, а не саму проблему.

Как возникает такая проблема:

1. У вас есть старый файл, в кодировке 866.
2. Вы читаете его в строку без указания кодировки. Система не находит BOM, и читает файл в кодировке `Encoding.Default`.
3. Вы пытаетесь "перекодировать прочитанную строку".

Пример:

```
// создали старый файл с содержимым в 866
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", "тест!", Encoding.GetEncoding(866));

// Открыли без указания кодировки, увидели кракозяблы:
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("test.txt"));
```

Решение, которое вы пытаетесь применить - это "сконвертировать строку". Т.е. вы надеетесь что следующий код сработает:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // создали старый файл с содержимым в 866
    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\test.txt", "тест!", Encoding.GetEncoding(866));

    // Открыли без указания кодировки, увидели кракозяблы:
    var text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
    Console.WriteLine(text);

    text = Convert(text, 866, 1251);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}

static string Convert(string source, int from, int to)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
    byte[] newBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(from), bytes);
    string newStr = Encoding.GetEncoding(to).GetString(newBytes);
    return newStr;
}
```

В этом решении есть слабое место - оно предполагает, строки в .net - это просто эдакий набор байт. Т.е. неважно в каком виде строка прочитана - ее можно обратно сконвертировать в те же самые байты, из которых ее прочитали. На самом деле это не так. Пример выше - нерабочий.

Если не угадать кодировку файла при чтении - его не получится записать назад.

```
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\test.txt", "тест!", Encoding.GetEncoding(866));

var text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
File.WriteAllText(@"test2.txt", text);
```

Внезапно, этот код выдает два разных файла, хотя никакого "перекодирования" не было.

---

Comment: Хорошо, если кодировка в «неправильную» кодовую страницу была без потерь, и её можно обратить.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, дописал примечание

Comment: Классно, спасибо!

Comment: @PashaPash _"File.ReadAllText("test.txt") ... Внезапно"_ -- дело в том, что вы пишете 866, а читаете UTF8. посмотрите [исходник](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,786)

Comment: @Stack так и проблема, описанная вами в вопросе, как раз в этом и заключается. кто-то где-то записал файл в 866 (или другой старой кодировке). Прочитали с указанием неправильной кодировки (или вообще без указания, и прочитался как utf-8) - получили кракозяблы. Суть ответа - надо читать в правильной кодировке сразу, указывая ее при чтении. А не чинить последствия "конвертацией".

Comment: @PashaPash _"Суть ответа - надо читать в правильной кодировке сразу, указывая ее при чтении"_ -- согласен. посмотрите в более общем случае, например, есть веб-сервис и приходит POST в котором присылают в кодировке 866, а позже приходит GET и хотят тоже самое в 1251. а потом наоборот. понятно, что надо менять кодировку по запросу.

Comment: @PashaPash _"никакого "перекодирования" не было."_ -- вызывается метод decoder.GetChars -- посмотрите [исходник](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,618). в нем кодировка 866 записанная вами в файл, перекодируется в utf8.

Comment: @Stack метод `decoder.GetChars` занимается не *пере*кодированием, а *де*кодированием. Это разные вещи.

Answer (score 2):

```
string Convert(string source, int from, int to)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
    byte[] newBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(from), bytes);
    string newStr = Encoding.GetEncoding(to).GetString(newBytes);
    return newStr;
}
```

Использование:

```
string str = "Привет";
string result = Convert(str, 866, 1251); => ЇаЁўҐв
string result2 = Convert(result, 1251, 866); => Привет
```

Comment: конвертирование в UTF8 в методе Convert излишне. можно сразу получить байты в нужной кодировке - `Encoding.GetEncoding(from).GetBytes(source)` и обойтись без вызова Encoding.Convert

Answer (score 0):

Есть строка "ЇаЁўҐв". Каким образом ее прочесть?

Ваш ['привет'.](http://alexpad.com/checking/866-1251:%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)
1251 и 866 обе однобайтные, поддерживают кириллицу и покрывают кодовый диапазон без потерь при неверной интерпретации (866-1251, 1251-866).

Если требуется только прочесть, то не нужно ничего конвертировать. Достаточно выбрать верную кодовую страницу для интерпретации текста, (как было отмечено коллегами ранее - у Вас cp866) и задать ее при чтении массива байт или из потока.

Варианты перечислены выше. Вот только не `Сonvert`, а то получите тоже самое, так-как `Convert` производит сопоставление, а не замену символов.